# Group by clause using zip and lambda in python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by

Suppose there are two rows such as names and marks as shown below:

```
Names      Marks
Sriyam     [10]
Epali      [10]
Sriyam     [12,13]
Rajendra   [10]
Shankar    [10]
Epali      [13,14]
```

How would i write a query using group by,lambda and zip function such that the new results should look like the below:
Here it will add the values for the corresponding names in the columns and sum it in a single variable and write the unique names once as shown below:

```
names     marks
Sriyam     [35]
Epali      [37]
Rajendra   [10]
Shankar    [10]
```

Comment: is this in pandas?

Comment: yes...The output will be like this instead


    names     marks
    Sriyam     [10,12,13]
    Epali      [10,13,14]
    Rajendra   [10]
    Shankar    [10]

Answer (score 3):

Using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
from itertools import chain

out = (df.groupby('Names')['Marks']
         .agg(lambda x: sum(chain.from_iterable(x)))
      )
```

Output:

```
Names
Epali       37
Rajendra    10
Shankar     10
Sriyam      35
Name: Marks, dtype: int64
```

Or, if you really want a list as output:

```
out = (df.groupby('Names')['Marks']
         .agg(lambda x: [sum(chain.from_iterable(x))])
      )
```

Output:

```
Names
Epali       [37]
Rajendra    [10]
Shankar     [10]
Sriyam      [35]
Name: Marks, dtype: object
```

##### merging the lists (efficiently!)

```
from itertools import chain

out = (df.groupby('Names')['Marks']
         .agg(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
      )
```

Output:

```
Names
Epali       [10, 13, 14]
Rajendra            [10]
Shankar             [10]
Sriyam      [10, 12, 13]
Name: Marks, dtype: object
```

##### timing of the different approaches

###### aggregation as sum

Shorter runtime is better.

*NB. for a better comparison, I standardized all codes to output a Series of sums with "Names" as index.*

As expected, the two solutions using `sum` to merge the lists (@Homayoon and @SomeDude) have quadratic complexity. The solution of @Chrise and mine are more efficient but `explode` is more costly than `itertools.chain`.

[image]

###### merging the lists

```
# mozway
(df.groupby('Names')['Marks']
   .agg(lambda x: sum(chain.from_iterable(x)))
)

# Chris
df.explode('Marks').groupby('Names')['Marks'].sum()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to sum or merge the lists?

Comment: merging the lists huh! Of course. Thanks for the comparisons! Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    "names": ["sriyam", "epali", "sriyam", "rajendra", "shankar", "epali"],
    "marks": [[10], [10], [12, 13], [10], [10], [13, 14]],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.groupby(by="names", axis=0).sum()
df["marks"] = df["marks"].apply(lambda s: sum(s))
# or df["marks"] = df["marks"].apply(lambda s: [sum(s)]) if you really want the sum to be in a list itself
```

I hope you wanted this in pandas :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using explode

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Names':['Sriyam','Epali','Sriyam','Rajendra','Shankar','Epali'],
        'Marks':[[10],[10],[12,13],[10],[10],[13,14]]
    }
)

df.explode('Marks').groupby('Names', as_index=False).sum()
```

Output

```
      Names  Marks
0     Epali     37
1  Rajendra     10
2   Shankar     10
3    Sriyam     35
```

if you prefer them to be merged lists

```
df.groupby('Names', as_index=False).sum()
```

Output

```
      Names         Marks
0     Epali  [10, 13, 14]
1  Rajendra          [10]
2   Shankar          [10]
3    Sriyam  [10, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It answered my question. But how would i write the code if the output would be like this instead,i.e. it will extend the list to all values for a particular name

    names     marks
    Sriyam     [10,12,13]
    Epali      [10,13,14]
    Rajendra   [10]
    Shankar    [10]

Comment: Thanks a lot..All of the approaches are working... But my query is that suppose for the name Sriyam,,there are three entries such as 10,12 and 13 in the marks column,, how would i display the output as Sriyam  [10,12,13]. Similarly it should populate for other names also.

Comment: Thanks a lot..All of the approaches are working... But my query is that suppose for the name Sriyam,,there are three entries such as 10,12 and 13 in the marks column,, how would i display the output as Sriyam  [10,12,13]. Similarly it should populate for other names also.

Comment: @Chris `df.groupby('Names', as_index=False).sum()` should only be used if you have 2 lists to merge, for more this is inefficient. Repeated list summation has a quadratic complexity (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df.groupby('Names', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: [sum(x.sum())])
```

Output:

```
      Names Marks
0     Epali  [37]
1  Rajendra  [10]
2   Shankar  [10]
3    Sriyam  [35]
```

Comment: It solved all my queries. Thanks a lot